# Uso de Break no Python

Tags: python, break

Eu fiz esse código que vai passando de fase, porém, quando se erra eu usei o Break para finalizar o jogo... mas ele apresenta a mensagem de Game Over e mesmo assim continua para a próxima fase... alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código:

```
#menu
hotel = [['*', '*', '_', 'G'], ['R','_', '*', '*']]

print('Seja bem vindo ao hotel dos animais!')
nome = input('Qual o seu nome, para que possamos iniciar? ')

print('{}, vamos iniciar nossa jogatina!...:'.format(nome))
sleep(5)
regras= [['Regras: O rato não pode ficar ao lado do gato.'],['O cão não pode ficar ao lado do osso.'], ['O gato não pode ficar ao lado do cão.'], ['O queijo não pode ficar ao lado do gato.']]
for linha in regras:
  print(linha)
sleep(5)

#fase1
print('Na fase 1 você deve alocar o Rato e o Gato na seguinte matriz que representa os quartos')

sleep(5)

for linha in hotel:
  print(linha)

sleep(5)

posRato = int(input("Qual a posição que o Rato deve ficar? "))
posGato = int(input('Qual a posição que o gato deve ficar? '))
while True:
  if posRato == 5 and posGato == 4:
    print('Parabéns {}, você segue para a fase 2!'.format(nome))
  else:
    print('Ops {}, infelizmente você perdeu!'.format(nome))
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o trecho que cita na dúvida não está descrito no código, mas o break irá parar o loop do while, se o restante do código estiver com a mesma indentação não será executado, mas caso esteja fora do while irá ser executado mesmo com o break, pois ele está parando somente o loop.

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou o break na condição correta que você quer que ele pare o programa, por exemplo se você colocar o break depois do print do if, ele vai fazer com que o programa pare sem executar o else.